# How do you alter the z axis length in a 3d excel plot?

Tags: excel, charts, 3d

I'm trying to plot 6 timeseries side by side in excel. The default 3d bar charts and surface plots *almost* do the right thing. The problem is the timeseries are laid on the z-axis as I expected but they're jammed so close together you can't read the labels.

I've tried changing the tick interval and re-sizing the chart. Re-sizing the chart only seems to affect the x and y axis lengths leaving the z-axis pretty much the same short useless length.

How do I change the z-axis length in Excel?

Comment: Honestly, there has to be a better option here than Excel for this. Do you know any other languages? R is free, & works quite well for this sort of thing.

Comment: @gung As I said, Excel *almost* does what I need. If it can't do what I need, then fine, I'll pick up a new tool but I'm hoping Excel isn't so brain dead as to not provide z-axis sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To adjust the z-axis size, do the following:

1. Select Layout/3D Rotation on the ribbon. A 3d rotation dialog box opens.
2. Ensure 3D Rotation is highlighted on the dialog's left pane and then deselect Autoscale at bottom the right pane in the dialog box.
3. To lengthen the z-axis, increase the Depth percentage from 100 to 200, 300 or whatever is needed to accommodate your z-axis labels.

A few other points - the graph itself is contained in a picture within the chart panel. You can lengthen the z-axis somewhat by clicking on the chart to select the chart's frame and then resize the frame.

If you're plotting time series data using the 3d bar graph, you can click on a specific bar and Excel will show you the datum value that produced the bar.

To look on the backside of the graph to see if there are hidden values, set the x-axis rotation to 135. Lengthening the z-axis alleviates the issue somewhat as it spreads the series further apart and lets you see "behind" the front series a bit better.